# Visualstudio macro - enumerating all projects properties

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I have a huge solution with many projects,  I would like to set a particular propertie (for example warning level)  for each of the projects. 
  Can this be done with a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DTE2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2.aspx) looks like it might provide access to that.  However, I suspect it might be simpler to write some kind of script (e.g., with awk, perl, ruby, python, etc.) that processes the files.  For example, if dealing with C/C++ projects, it could spin through the .vcproj files and add/change lines as needed.